# plotting; adding own x-axis does not work

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I would like to plot time-series data. To illustrate the dates on the x-asis, I first removed the values on the axis to then add my on axsis with the correct dates:

```
set.seed(1)
r <- rnorm(20,0,1)
z <- c(1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1)
data <- as.data.frame(na.omit(cbind(z, r)))
series1 <- ts(cumsum(c(1,data[,2]*data[,1])))
series2 <- ts(cumsum(c(1,data[,2])))
d1y <- seq(as.Date("1991-01-01"),as.Date("2015-01-01"),length.out=24)

plot_strategy <- function(series1, series2, currency)
  {x11()
 matplot(cbind(series1, series2), xaxt = "n", xlab = "Time", 
         ylab = "Value", col = 1:3, ann = TRUE, type = 'l', 
         lty = 1)
 axis(1, at=as.POSIXct(d1y),labels=format(d1y,"%Y"))
 title(ylab = "Value")
 title(xlab = "Time")

 legend(x = "topleft", legend = c("TR", "BA"),
        lty = 1,col = 1:3)
 dev.copy2pdf(file= currency, width = 11.69, height = 8.27)}

plot_strategy(series1, series2,
              currency= "all.pdf")
```

However, the new x-axis doesn't show up. Any suggestions?

Comment: In `axis(1, at=as.POSIXct(d1y),labels=format(d1y,"%Y"))`, `at` should be between 1 and 21, i.e. the length of "series1" and "series2".

Comment: It is still not working... any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set.seed(1)
r <- rnorm(20,0,1)
z <- c(1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1)
data <- as.data.frame(na.omit(cbind(z, r)))
series1 <- ts(cumsum(c(1,data[,2]*data[,1])))
series2 <- ts(cumsum(c(1,data[,2])))
d1y <- seq(as.Date("1991-01-01"),as.Date("2015-01-01"),length.out=24)

matplot(cbind(series1, series2), xaxt = "n", xlab = "Time", 
        ylab = "Value", col = 1:3, ann = TRUE, type = 'l',  
        lty = 1)
axis(1, at=seq(2,20,2), labels=format(d1y[seq(2,20,2)],"%Y"))
```

[image]

Comment: It indeed works. Thanks :) In order to give an simple example of my problem, I created an example with just 20 value. But the actual data I'm using contains 6334 values, whereas the time horizion stays the same.  I change the code into: `axis(1, at=seq(2,6334,365), labels=format(d1y[seq(2,6334,365)],"%Y"))`. But now the there are again no values on the x-axis. What is my mistake?